# AngularJS ui-select performance issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ui-select, md-autocomplete

I'm using UI Select control in my application(source - https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/).
It has a major performance issue(lagging when populated wuth over ~2000 items).
Tried using also mdAutocomplete(source - https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)
since it already supports virtualization but the problem with this one is that it creates a huge amount of watchers(if list has 5000 items it creates ~15000 watchers although only 20 items are rendered at a time).
Any insights regarding how to solve this performance issues in any of the control.
I'll note i have to support a large amount of items - ~10K items.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make sure you have `order by` in your `ui-select-choices` iteration loop

Comment: you mean in the repeat statement?

Comment: yes, in repeat.

Answer (score 2):

there is no direct solution for this but yes a good workaround is available:
limit your dropdown results to a particular number unless it is been search..exa.

```
repeat="username in users | filter: $select.search | limitTo: ($select.search.length <= 1) ? 50 : 20">
```

Or some other logic. In any case, showing 10K results in dropdown at a time is not even useful for user.